# Best Email Host or Solution For Large Volume of Automated Emails

Tags: email, smtp, spam

I run a service which send's people alerts via email. I am launching a new version and switched over a bunch of stuff to GoDaddy, but it looks like there is a limit of 250 SMTP relays per day so this is no good for me.

My old email account is on spam lists now (although I never spam, my emails look very similar daily and are predictably sent).

What would be the best solution?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option so far for sending email in volume is looking for a mail provider, there's several of them around that will relay your email and guarantee deliverability (while your business is 100% legit of course).

I'm using http://www.authsmtp.com/ to send all my user emails (I'm running from EC2 so SMTP deliverability is poor) and they do an amazing job, depending on the needs you have you can also look at other SMTP providers.

Comment: any experience with http://sendgrid.com/ ?

Comment: I've not used them but I've heard about them several times, they're one of the power players on this, so you can't really go wrong using them